# Consider a lottery with $n^2$ tickets, of which exactly $n$ win prizes. A person buys $2n$ tickets. Find the following limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a lottery with $n^2$ tickets, of which exactly $n$ win prizes. A person buys $2n$ tickets. Find the following limits: (a) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb P$(at least one winning tickets)=
(b) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb P$(exactly 3 winning tickets)=

For (a) and (b), I can get the expression but don't know to find the limits, so I'm wondering whether there are easier ways to express the limits.

I get (a): $1 - \frac{{2n \choose n^2 - n}}{n^2 \choose 2n}$. (b)=$ \frac{{n \choose 3}{2n-3 \choose n^2 - n}}{n^2 \choose 2n}$. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Stirling approximation of $k!$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, I tried actually but didn't simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards a) the probability should be
$$1 - \frac{{n^2-n \choose 2n}}{n^2 \choose 2n}=1 - \frac{(n^2-n)! (n^2-2n)!}{(n^2)!(n^2-3n)!}\sim 1-\frac{1}{e^2},$$
because by [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),
$$(n^2-a\cdot n)!\sim \sqrt{2\pi} n\cdot\frac{n^{2(n^2-an)}}{e^{n^2-a^2/2}}.$$
For b) the probability is 
$$\frac{{n \choose 3}{n^2-n \choose 2n-3}}{n^2 \choose 2n}
\sim \frac{\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot {n^2-n \choose 2n}\cdot \frac{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)}{(n^2-3n+3)(n^2-3n+2)(n^2-3n+1)}}{{n^2 \choose 2n}}\sim \frac{8/6}{e^2}=\frac{4}{3e^2}.$$

Comment: Which is what one would expect heuristically. For large $n$ there’s little difference between drawing $2n$ tickets with and without replacement. If they’re drawn with replacement, the probability of drawing $2n$ losing tickets is $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{2n}\to\frac1{e^2}$ as $n\to\infty$.